# My created user don't have default permission (add,delete,change)?

Tags: python, django, user-permissions

I'm new in Django and I will be happy if someone help me.
I create user in command line,and my user doen't have "add" permission and other defult(delete, change) permission too!!

```
>>> b = User.objects.create_user('mina','mina@dd.dd','123456')
>>> b.save()
>>> b.has_perm('student.add_user')
False
```

this is my setting installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'student',  
)
```

and my model 'user':

```
class user(models.Model):
    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)
    password=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    user_id=models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    phone=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    task=models.ForeignKey(task)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user_id', 'task')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'name:%s--------IDnumber:%s' % (self.name,str(self.user_id))
```

Why user doesn't have these permission? and What can I do to add that permission?
I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only superuser has all permissions. Permissions should be added to non-superusers.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

...

b.user_permissions.add(Permission.objects.get(content_type__app_label='student',
                                              codename='add_user'))
b.user_permissions.add(Permission.objects.get(content_type__app_label='student',
                                              codename='change_user'))
b.user_permissions.add(Permission.objects.get(content_type__app_label='student',
                                              codename='delete_user'))
```

Comment: thanks alot.I think defult permission works for all user.It's works now.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group, Permission

b = User.objects.create_user('mina','mina@dd.dd','123456') 
permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Can add user') # get permission by name
b.user_permissions.add(permission) #add permission to user
b.save()
```

Or you can create a `group` with all permissons that you want, and add user to this group like this:

```
group = Group.objects.get(name='wizard')
user.groups.add(group)
```

And take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a custom user model. Your user model needs to inherit the PermissionsMixin

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
```

Also it's recommended that your model inherits from AbstractBaseUser

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
```